# how to Browse the database from android Device?

Tags: android

I am designing an app in android, for my app i created one database for data storage now i want to browse my app database from device so that i can monitor my tables and it's data. I am able to browse the database from AVD(using SQLite Database Browser) but it's not working for the device, so pls guide me.

Thanks,
Balaram.

Answer (score 1):

Balaram , currently there is no way to browse database on the device (the way you want it) (without getting the root permission) similar to browsing on a SQLite Database Browser

While to browse the database on the device you need to follow programmatic steps given here at  ['Using your own SQLite database in Android applications'](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Does this still hold true? That there is no other way except rooting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to root the phone and get SuperUser permission to access app databases. The database will (after getting root) then be available in the "/data/data/com.your.application/databases" folder. Also, after getting root on your phone, you will a file browser capable of using the SU permission to display system files. For e.g. Root Explorer.

What works in the AVD works exactly the same on the device. Ideally, there is no need to grab your DB from the device. But if you must, be careful with the other system files.